# conditionally update column with SQL (in Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way in SQL to conditionally update a column with one or another value?

I have this update sql (paraphrased):

```
UPDATE LMPROC_LIMITS
   SET LIMIT = sign(LIMIT) * 100 * floor(0.000001 + (sign(LIMIT) * LIMIT * ratio/100)
 WHERE SYMBOL_ID = symbolId
   AND CLASSTYPE = LimitType
   AND TYPE_ IN (
                 'minClusterPosition', 
                 'maxClusterPosition',
                 'minProductPosition', 
                 'maxProductPosition', 
                 'minBookPosition',
                 'maxBookPosition', 
                 'maxShortShares'
                )
```

(ratio, symbolId, and LimitType all are filled in at run time)

What I want to do is limit (no pun intended) the value LIMIT is set to to +/-2,147,483,647 - i.e. if the result of (sign(LIMIT) * 100 * floor(0.000001 + (sign(LIMIT) * LIMIT * ratio/100)) is more or less then that, I want to set it to +/-2,147,483,647 Can I do this in SQL?

This is in Oracle

Comment: You can do a CASE statement

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but you can use `case` in sql to achieve conditional updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CASE statement:

```
update LMPROC_LIMITS
set LIMIT = 
  case 
    when sign(LIMIT) * 100 * floor(0.000001 + (sign(LIMIT) * LIMIT * ratio/100) > 2147483647 then 2147483647
    when sign(LIMIT) * 100 * floor(0.000001 + (sign(LIMIT) * LIMIT * ratio/100) < -2147483647 then - 2147483647
    else sign(LIMIT) * 100 * floor(0.000001 + (sign(LIMIT) * LIMIT * ratio/100)
  end       
where SYMBOL_ID = symbolId
and CLASSTYPE = LimitType
and TYPE_ in ('minClusterPosition', 'maxClusterPosition',
'minProductPosition', 'maxProductPosition', 'minBookPosition',
'maxBookPosition', 'maxShortShares')
```

Also in your specific example combination of GREATEST and LEAST function would do the trick as well.

Comment: Thanks - this works for me, but now the requirement has been slightly changed - I have to know in the program that I set LIMIT to +/- 2147483647 and I need to take some other programmatic action in that case. I don't see how I can possibly do that without having multiple queries.

Comment: Someone pointed me at the 'returning' clause - that looks like just what I need.